# Is there a way to dynamically change the zorder of selected points in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

I have an Altair plot with multiple points in similar *xy* position, similar to [this plot](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#selection-targets-fields-and-encodings) in the Altair tutorial. Since I use tooltips, I'd like for the selected points to rise to the top (i.e. increase zorder in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) terminology). Is there a way to do this? (If not, I'm happy to file a feature request!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the z-order of the points is set by the order of each subchart within the layers, and this cannot be adjusted dynamically. This is fairly central to Vega-Lite's rendering model, and unlikely to be changed.

One trick you can use to achieve what you want, though, is to overlay a duplicate chart which is filtered by the selection in question, to make selected points appear above all others. Here is an example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()

selection = alt.selection_single(on='mouseover', nearest=True)

base = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.condition(selection, 'Origin:N', alt.value('lightgray'))
)

alt.layer(
  base.add_selection(selection),
  base.transform_filter(selection).encode(tooltip='Name:N'),
)
```

[Live Chart View](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6bYwIAuy8ArrDQM4DqyAJhQBakAsADLwBooceFVr0GACQJoOFUgGZ+AX2UDwUADYBDAJ4EATqQDaGiKAiWoAW20GA1qUgAHWNXnqrESAXhxW1OhYFl7ecJqwRsFmocIIAVQIpCGxlpAUus4ETvCw1tTampCeqWkoBJqsTgDyBmjUxTGpkAwVBNCJ8E6tmu0UkfwArJBNXmqjVniFNNlYkJqyFKgGeiOp480AHsnpmbNQAI402qLIFNpUuNlCkOWVTpKRra5EhpAbsZC6OxlZTkcnKjnS7XKB3KpzACyyF6DAA+lkDHCAOKFCJdZSjD6THp9ZBJaLNXEdAa8YbBXZ-OYMQK9YpQAk2CQEWBXIw3eAEOwEBjyLAUAwzTGhYWWbHYUaQWwOJyudyNUI+PywALwIIS5rhSLJCZpEQJfFdQmlby-faQXL5eCFBUmsGEe5zWr1LolE0tNodQ3dT39AxDNalcWK3DTc0LVByZarXXBtL9WCaKjOH57HJ5ApFG7gpwAOW01myce82wpZv+x1OwOQV3ptwdEKgjwMz1gryMxag3zLabmAKrFxroPrFUbkGhsIRhhRaKSoqscfSK3gDEQkWsJhwKCTbwpxM6Pt6JP9ZPeygAujFReeSpBWBdtDsaAYinM5BRnAwMAB6b9XVDaAAdKgZwcDQABGgH4n+BAAQAtPe5ytBQDDfoh2jftAdgMIBABWDBzreAAkDDQBwBC2E476fj+MEAcBoEQVBsDfqR5G2HR2hwQsFAEH+3CAbwgl4QRXQgMoQA)